# Comparison of different values from ResultSet to database SQL Query

Tags: java, resultset

I'm new to java.I have a SQL Query that gives the following output

```
logtime 2014-09-02 16:05:10.0

BL1_data_SS_ST 2      

BL2_data_SS_ST 2

BL3_data_SS_ST 2

BL4_data_SS_ST 1

BL5_data_SS_ST 0

BL6_data_SS_ST 2

/* continues till BL27_data_SS_ST */

st1_prmt_status_p45 1

beam_current  110.58 

beam_energy 2500.0635
```

I have only one row in my output and 31 columns. I'm using Java and JSP .

---

**EDIT**

The above result is retrieved by the following method

```
public String[][] beamline_Status() {
  int i = 0;
  try {
    con = getConnection();
    stmt = con.createStatement();

    String sql = "SELECT TOP 1 c.logtime, a.BL1_data_SS_ST,a.BL2_data_SS_ST,a.BL3_data_SS_ST,a.BL4_data_SS_ST,a.BL5_data_SS_ST,a.BL6_data_SS_ST,a.BL7_data_SS_ST,a.BL8_data_SS_ST,a.BL9_data_SS_ST,a.BL10_data_SS_ST,a.BL11_data_SS_ST, a.BL12_data_SS_ST,a.BL13_data_SS_ST,a.BL14_data_SS_ST,a.BL15_data_SS_ST,a.BL16_data_SS_ST,a.BL17_data_SS_ST,a.BL18_data_SS_ST,a.BL19_data_SS_ST,a.BL20_data_SS_ST,a.BL21_data_SS_ST,a.BL22_data_SS_ST,a.BL23_data_SS_ST,a.BL24_data_SS_ST,a.BL25_data_SS_ST,a.BL26_data_SS_ST,a.BL27_data_SS_ST,b.st1_prmt_status_p45,c.beam_current,c.beam_energy from INDUS2_BLFE.dbo.main_BLFE_status a inner join INDUS2_MSIS.dbo.main_MSIS_status b on a.logtime=b.logtime inner join INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT c on b.logtime=c.logtime ORDER BY c.logtime DESC ";

    stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    rs = stmt.getResultSet();

    while (rs.next()) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 31; j++) {
        a[i][j] = rs.getString(j + 1);
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("\nException (String code):" + e);
  } finally {
    closeConnection(stmt, rs, con);
  }
  return a;
}
```

Now I wan to define a method which retrieve values from the `ResultSet` where column values are either `0` or `1`. How to do that.

EDIT 2

I'm trying to retrieve the column values from resultset where column value is 1 by following code:-

```js
public String[][] beam_CurrentStatus() {
  int i = 0;
  try

  {
    con = getConnection();
    stmt = con.createStatement();

    String sql = "SELECT TOP 1 c.logtime, a.BL1_data_SS_ST,a.BL2_data_SS_ST,a.BL3_data_SS_ST,a.BL4_data_SS_ST,a.BL5_data_SS_ST,a.BL6_data_SS_ST,a.BL7_data_SS_ST,a.BL8_data_SS_ST,a.BL9_data_SS_ST,a.BL10_data_SS_ST,a.BL11_data_SS_ST, a.BL12_data_SS_ST,a.BL13_data_SS_ST,a.BL14_data_SS_ST,a.BL15_data_SS_ST,a.BL16_data_SS_ST,a.BL17_data_SS_ST,a.BL18_data_SS_ST,a.BL19_data_SS_ST,a.BL20_data_SS_ST,a.BL21_data_SS_ST,a.BL22_data_SS_ST,a.BL23_data_SS_ST,a.BL24_data_SS_ST,a.BL25_data_SS_ST,a.BL26_data_SS_ST,a.BL27_data_SS_ST,b.st1_prmt_status_p45,c.beam_current,c.beam_energy from INDUS2_BLFE.dbo.main_BLFE_status a inner join INDUS2_MSIS.dbo.main_MSIS_status b on a.logtime=b.logtime inner join INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT c on b.logtime=c.logtime ORDER BY c.logtime DESC ";

    stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    rs = stmt.getResultSet();

    while (rs.next()) {
      for (int j = 1; j < 31; j++) {
        if ((rs.getString(j)) == "1")

          a[i][j] = rs.getString(j + 1);

      }


    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("\nException in:" + e);
  } finally {
    closeConnection(stmt, rs, con);
  }

  return a;


}
```

But the result I'm getting of above code is

> [[Ljava.lang.String;@ea25c1

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but `select * from table where col1 = 1 or col1 = 2`

Comment: Do you want to obtain entire table in a ResultSet or just the  1st and 2nd column.?

Comment: `ResultSet` index starts from `1` and not from `0`

Answer (score 0):

If you want entire table in the `ResultSet` and then obtain only the first and second column out of it you can do like:

```
 Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery("select * from tableName");
 rs.getInt(1);      //assuming your column is of compatible type
 rs.getInt(2);
```

or the other way is that you retrieve only the first two columns from the DB into your `ResultSet`

Comment: I don't want to retrieve only the first two columns ,I want to retrieve only those columns where the corresponding value of column is either 0 0r 1.For eg:- The values of  BL1_data_SS_ST,BL2_data_SS_ST,BL3_data_SS_ST ,BL4_data_SS_ST  is 2,2 2,1.So want to retrieve only these column.Moreover logtime,beam_energy and beam_current will be retrieved irrespective of the values of other columns.

Comment: Try obtaining the entire table in a `ResultSet` then using the getXXX methods you can check for the desired values ..if it matches then obtain the entries in a data structure